# Disable open when file drag and dropped to web browser

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

When dragging and dropping files to Internet Explorer and Chrome, they both open the file that was dragged and dropped.  I would like to disable this functionality so that the dragged and dropped file does not automatically open.

Is this a browser setting or a Windows setting?

Comment: What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: We have a web app that has a drop area and we want the files to upload without opening.

Comment: what's really strange is that dragging and dropping the file to Chrome doesn't open the file for 99% of our users (there's only a few that Chrome opens the file for).  With that said, IE 9 and 10 open the file 100% of the time.

Comment: This would be an issue with your drag and drop javascript or HTML, rather than an issue with a browser.  The file is being opened because the drag and drop code is not triggering.  It will still not trigger if you disable file-open in the browser.  Best to try to debug the code.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well Paul but for it to not open for 99% of our chrome users made me think that the issue was elsewhere.  And why would it work one way in chrome and another way in IE?

Comment: From the comments is is clear that this is not a software issue with your browser, but that you are programming. Therefore your question is off-topic here and it should be on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) I suggest you place it there **but show the relevant parts of your code** otherwise it will get closed as having insufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question is both.
In browser console:

```
window.addEventListener("dragover",null)
window.addEventListener("drop",null)
```

Will disable responds to dragevent within browser and you can turn this into a java bookmarklet. However,

the behaviour is about your operating systems UI and chrome itself. UI sends a message to chrome process that something is dragged over. Chrome responds. You can block either of them as a definite solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you are looking for...**

```
 $( '#div_yourdroparea' ).bind( 'dragover',function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();    
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
    $( '#div_yourdroparea' ).bind( 'drop',function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();   
      event.preventDefault();

    //your upload code goes here....
        }
```

Comment: How should this could help at solving the OP's problem?